# События на очередность скролов

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день.
Нужно последовательности скроллов присваивать некоторые события:

- первый скролл (любой дискретности/интервала) - появление блока
- второй скролл (любой дискретности/интервала) - переезд вниз на следующий слайд
- третий скролл (любой дискретности/интервала) - замена фонового изображения
- четвертый скролл (любой дискретности/интервала) - переезд вниз на следующий слайд

плюс в обратную сторону действует та же логика. 
спасибо.

Comment: @godan, согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам для размышлений. прокрутку в обратную сторону думайте сами.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ry6RX/)

```
var iterator = 0, timeout;
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(){
    console.log('------')
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        iterator = iterator++ >= 4 ? 1 : iterator++;
        console.log(iterator)
        switch(iterator){
            case 1:
                console.log('появление блока')
            break;
            case 2:
                console.log('переезд вниз на следующий слайд')
            break;
            // далее по аналогии
        }
    }, 200);
})
```